# lead module listview email colum to make sortable

Tags: sugarcrm

i want to make email column of list view in lead module make sortable.

I try to customized listviewdef file make 'sortable' => true but it not working it generate blank list

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

A workaround could be to add a column to the lead table that is normal text, and you copy the email address into that column after each update / add (using hooks).

You will then be able to sort by that column, but not be able to click on it to bring up the email editor.